# How to know who performed downvote

Tags: support, down-votes

Can someone please advise: Is there any chance to know who performed a downvote on my answer?

Comment: No, there isn't, and for good reason. Not even a mod can see that info

Comment: @Lamak mods can see it, afaik.

Comment: Your question itself was possibly down-voted for the reason of being ***poorly researched***, because there is an answer if you go and look around a bit. More in my answer.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Nope, we most certainly cannot.

Comment: *mostly*? not sure about that..? I know Paul has said he *can* see things we can't see -- specifically when *that* user deleted his account and caused the royal shit storm across the network, admins knew who it was but were bound not to say by the EULA.

Comment: @EvanCarroll "most certainly" ≠ "mostly". I'm sure there are things that elected moderators can see that regular users can't, and there may well be scenarios where mods are not at liberty to disclose what they know. However, when it comes to upvotes or downvotes on posts, I believe mods are exactly like us, regular users, in that they would be as much in the dark about who cast those as you or I would be.

Comment: @Evan We can deduce things when an extraordinary event happens like a user is deleted, just like any of you can, but we absolutely cannot directly associate a vote with a user. Why would I lie about this? "We can see things you can't see" does not equate to "oh he must have meant associating a vote with a user." He didn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to DBA.SE. If you take some time to look around a bit on the main DBA.SE site and on the META DBA.SE site, you will find the help center which provides you with a wealth of information.

In the article [Why is voting important?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) there is a section that states:

> Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, **while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information.** The more that people vote on a post, the more certain future visitors can be of the quality of information contained within that post – not to mention that upvotes are a great way to thank the author of a good post for the time and effort put into writing it!

<sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

And in the article [What is reputation? How do I earn (**and lose**) it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will find the following statement:

> You lose reputation when:
>
> - your question is voted down: −2
> - your answer is voted down: −2
> - you vote down an answer: −1
> - you place a bounty on a question: − full bounty amount
> - one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags: −100
>
> All users start with one reputation point, and reputation can never drop below 1. Accepting your own answer does not increase your reputation. Deleted posts do not affect reputation, for voters, authors or anyone else involved, in most cases. If a user reverses a vote, the corresponding reputation loss or gain will be reversed as well. Vote reversal as a result of voting fraud will also return lost or gained reputation.

<sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

If I were to leave this answer as it is know, then I would possibly receive down-votes, because I have not yet answered your question:

> ...is there any chance to know who performed downvote on my answer?

### Answering Your Question

There is a question on the main meta site titled [Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12984) which was answered as follows:

> No, voting is by design anonymous. Not even ♦ moderators have access to information on individual votes.
>
> The only way you will find out who voted for you is if someone decides to leave a comment saying so and maybe their reason. This doesn't mean they couldn't be lying also.
>
> (To tell if, and how, you voted on a specific post, your votes are stored in a database. And of course Stack Exchange employees do have access to that information, but it's only used in exceptional circumstances, such as investigating voting fraud.)

### Supportive Answer

Your question was deemed by some of the community, to be either...

- containing wrong information
- being poorly researched
- failing to communicate information
- failing to meet the community's quality standards

In order to turn the down-votes into up-votes you could do one of the following:

- increase the information in your answer
- increase the credibility in your answer by citing sources and providing links (like I did in this answer)
- ask for clarification in a comment, why your answer was down-voted
- by deleting your answer altogether (*while this won't change the down-votes, it will remove them*)

The community as a whole is normally very thoughtful when it comes to down-voting, because it does subtract reputation from the user who is down-voting.

Hope this answer was helpful. Feel free to down-vote if you think I did not answer your question.

Comment: Hello @hot2use, Many thanks for explanation (not at all down-vote, up-voted). But it's interesting to see this question down-votes. though, it was asked since the information not found in help-center. agree with you that there is question already **main meta**, but by that time (when questioned) i was new member of DBA.SE, could not find that question (Main SE). However, the intention is to know just for my knowledge base. Once again thank you all!